# ¿Por qué al convertir "0125" con int() se convierte en "125"?

Tags: python, números-enteros

Estoy usando Python 3.x para leer un número con el método `input()`.

Cuando inserto 0125 y luego lo convierto en `int()` quiero que me almacene 0125 pero me almacena 125. ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Utilizo esto para que cuando yo haga un condicional `if` y pueda evaluar la clave que ingreso con las de un diccionario, siendo evaluada correctamente sin que me mande un KeysError.

Comment: ¿Por qué es necesario el `0`? ¿las claves del diccionario son enteros o strings? si es string no es necesario convertirlo a entero.

Comment: Sería interesante que compartieras algo de tu código, pues lo mismo este diccionario puede pensarse de otra manera.

Comment: Las claves las necesito en enteros pero, me doy cuenta que es mejor interpretarlas como string es más rentable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al almacenarlo como numero entero, te elimina los ceros que tienes a la izquierda. Para mantenerlos tienes que tratarlo como texto.

Te dejo algunos ejemplos que puede que te sirvan a la hora de comparar los datos con las claves del diccionario:

```
diccionario = {'0125': 'la clave es un STRING', 125: 'La clave es un ENTERO'}

comparar1 = 125  # Tipo int
comparar2 = '0125'  # Tipo str

print(diccionario[comparar1])  # Devuelve La clave es un ENTERO
print(diccionario['0' + str(comparar1)])  # Devuelve La clave es un STRING

print(diccionario[comparar2])  # Devuelve la clave es un STRING
print(diccionario[int(comparar2)])  # Devuelve La clave es un ENTERO
```